# Pivot multiple tables using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, pivot

Hi I have following tables that needs to be pivoted to get the desired results.

```
tblUsername
userId      username
---------------------
 1          jadam
 2          janeb
 3          peterk
 4          rickd
```

second table is

```
tablcolumns
=============
colId     colname
-----------------
  1        Name
  2        Monday
  3        Tuesday
  4        Wednesday
  5        Thursday
  6        Friday
  7        Saturday
  8        Sunday
```

third table

```
tblSchedule
==================
id   userId   colId   hrs
--------------------------
1      2       3       4
2      3       7       7.5
3      1       8       2 
I am trying to write Linq statem
```

I want to pivot these tables to get reply back like

```
Name  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday 
jadam   2
janeb           4
peterk                                            7.5
rickd
```

I tried to use Linq join but it didnt work I believe it needs to be grouped, and I am not too familiar with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in pivot functionality in LINQ. I suppose you could write one to dynamically create the select - however, it probably wouldn't be too efficient. Anyway, for this case, since the number of days per week won't change, you can do this:

```
var query = tblUsername.Select(u => new {
    Name = u.username,
    Monday = u.tblSchedule.Where(sch => sch.colId == 2).Sum(sch => sch.hrs),
    Tuesday = u.tblSchedule.Where(sch => sch.colId == 3).Sum(sch => sch.hrs),
    Wednesday = u.tblSchedule.Where(sch => sch.colId == 4).Sum(sch => sch.hrs),
    Thursday = u.tblSchedule.Where(sch => sch.colId == 5).Sum(sch => sch.hrs),
    Friday = u.tblSchedule.Where(sch => sch.colId == 6).Sum(sch => sch.hrs),
    Saturday = u.tblSchedule.Where(sch => sch.colId == 7).Sum(sch => sch.hrs),
    Sunday = u.tblSchedule.Where(sch => sch.colId == 8).Sum(sch => sch.hrs),
});
```